# jqGrid client-side searching

Tags: jqgrid, client-side

I would like to manually apply searching to my jqGrid via JavaScript. I have tried a guide [here](http://d3developer.com/2010/08/09/client-side-search-with-jqgrid/), but can't seem to get it completely working.
In the grid setup I have a column with name 'error_column' that I would like to perform a search on looking for the string 'Test'.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var filter = { "field": "error_column", 'oper': 'eq', "data": 'Test' };
$("Grid2").jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true, postData: { filters: filter} })
$("Grid2").trigger('reloadGrid');
```

When I click the button that this is bound to, nothing happens and it causes no errors.

**EDIT**
Here is the code for initializing the grid:

```
jQuery("#Grid2").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames: ['NewSubscriberID', 'Conflicting Subscriber ID', 'Error Field', 'Error Message'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'new_subscriber_id', index: 'new_subscriber_id', width: 120},
        { name: 'conflicting_subscriber_id', index: 'conflicting_subscriber_id', width: 170},
        { name: 'error_column', index: 'error_column', width: 90, sorttype: "text", search: true},
        { name: 'error_type', index: 'error_type', width: 145}
    ],
    loadonce: true
    });
```

I bind the data to the grid using a local array.

Comment: Do you use advance searching (`multipleSearch:true`) or not? If you use toolbar searching it is important whether you use `stringResult:true` or not. It would be better if you include more code in your question.

Comment: I do not use multiple search as the data only needs to be searched on the one column. I updated the question to include the initialization code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should implement search for single field in a little another way:

```
var grid = jQuery("#Grid2");
var postdata = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
jQuery.extend (postdata,
               {filters:'',
                searchField: 'error_column',
                searchOper: 'eq',
                searchString: 'Test'});
grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true, postData: postdata });
grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]);
```

You can see live example [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SingleSearchFilter.htm).

**UPDATED**: You use `loadonce: true` and `datatype: "local"` together. The value `loadonce: true` will be ignored in case of `datatype: "local"`. If you do get the data from the server and use `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"`, then `loadonce: true` will work. If you want that the searching (filtering) will be done not locally but on the server instead you should reset `datatype` to `'json'` or `'xml'` as additional option of `'setGridParam'`.

Comment: FYI I altered it to support multi-search like this:

        `var grid = jQuery("#list27");
        var postdata = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
        jQuery.extend (postdata,
            {filters:'{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"field1","op":"ge","data":"search string here"},{"field":"field2","op":"ge","data":"search string here"}]}'});
        grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true, postData: postdata });
        grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]);`

Comment: @aknatn: you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5273385/315935) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5750127/315935) shown how to construct `filters` as object and then serialize it to JSON with `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @Oleg what is the fix exactly (for the single search VS filters).. ? is it the call to .extend() to pass in original values ??