# Adding filter buttons to a JQGrid Toolbar

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'd like to add a button to the JQGrid Toolbar that would say something like [Show Inactive], and when clicked, filters the data within the grid to display according to my programatically created search criteria.  Is this possible?  Annoyingly, there's a "filter toolbar", which hampers Googling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you will find all answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024075/jqgrid-navigation-based-on-the-selected-row/3024278#3024278), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492963/jqgrid-client-side-searching/4509018#4509018) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974324/jqgrid-using-multiple-methods-to-filter-data/3979490#3979490) answer. First of all you should add your custom button with respect of [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons). Then you should set the filter with respect of `postData` and `search:true` parameters of jqGrid and trigger `reloadGrid`.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926537/live-integrated-search-toolbar-in-jqgrid)