# jqGrid Filtering Records

Tags: search, jqgrid, filter

It seems there have been a few questions here regarding this subject, and they have some great answers, but it seems that my case is a little different.  I need to filter the records displayed in a jqGrid, but entirely client-side.

For a number of reasons, the best way for me to populate my grid is with an array that's emitted directly into the JavaScript on the page.  The grid itself doesn't interact with the server at all.  I have some custom AJAX happening in various grid events, but that's it.  (Basically, I'm integrating this with an existing set of available services which can't change significantly.)

What I'm looking to do is filter the grid based on a simple text input and button.  My page has the text input, the button, and a table (which becomes the grid on document ready).  I'd like to bind to the click event of the button (normal jQuery event binding, nothing special) and use the value from the text input as a display filter on the jqGrid.

By "filter" I mean to display only the records which contain a match (in any field) for the text in the input.  Then, to display all records, just empty the input and click the button again.  Additionally, the grid is multi-select and the selections need to persist through filtering.  I just need to be able to hide the rows which don't match what's in the input.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To filter local grid you should only fill `filters` property of the `postData` parameter of jqGrid and set additionally `search:true`.

To save selection of the grid you can use `reloadGrid` with additional parameter `[{page:1,current:true}]` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807623/jqgrid-paging-question/3808014#3808014)).

The corresponding code can be the following

```
$("#search").click(function() {
    var searchFiler = $("#filter").val(), grid = $("#list"), f;

    if (searchFiler.length === 0) {
        grid[0].p.search = false;
        $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:""});
    }
    f = {groupOp:"OR",rules:[]};
    f.rules.push({field:"name",op:"cn",data:searchFiler});
    f.rules.push({field:"note",op:"cn",data:searchFiler});
    grid[0].p.search = true;
    $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:JSON.stringify(f)});
    grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1,current:true}]);
});
```

I made [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridFiltered.htm) for you which filter for two columns 'Client' ('name') and 'Notes' ('note') you can extend the code to search in all columns which you need.

Depend on what you exactly mean with the saving row selection you can need to save the current selection from the [selarrrow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) in a variable and restore the selected rows with respect of [setSelection](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method.

Comment: This looks great, thanks!  A couple odd things are happening for me.  1: In IE 8 (my project's only target browser, client's orders) on my client-supplied environment it says `JSON` is undefined. But it _doesn't_ say this on your demo in the same browser. 2: In the demo you set up it's not saving the selection of rows between filtering. Rows which are selected, hidden, then un-hidden are no longer selected. However, while implementing this, I had an idea that may work simpler and more natively with jqGrid...

Comment: What if, instead of filtering the main grid, the filter functionality instead pops up a jQuery UI modal dialog (easy) which has its own grid which displays the filtered records (can I easily populate `grid2` with a filtered data set from `grid1`? I imagine worst case is I copy the array and filter in a loop with plain JS before setting it as the data to `grid2`). Then the user selects what they want and closes the modal dialog. On close, I get the selected IDs from `grid2` (easy) and set them as selected in `grid1` (easy, demo is on the jqGrid site). And, of course, clear `grid2`. Thoughts?

Comment: @David: You has "`JSON` is undefined" error because you don't included [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). IE8 has also native support of `JSON` class if the update [976662](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976662) is installed. I recommend you always include json2.js to be sure that `JSON.stringify` work.

Comment: @David: About the selection. jqGrid hold in `selarrrow` the array of selected rows on the **current visible page**. It is frequently not one need. So you will have to save all selected rows before the the user press "Search" button (`$("#list")[0].p.selarrrow` or `$("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow')`). Later you will have to update the external array in `onSelectRow` or in `beforeSelectRow` event handle. To set selection from the external array on the grid you should call in the loop `setSelection` method inside of `loadComplete` event handle.

Comment: @David: If you want create new grid with the same contain I would recommend you to use `data` parameter of jqGrid. You can get it with respect of `$("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','data')`. You will get the **full** grid contain (from all pages and independent from the current filters). In new grid you can use `data` as the parameter. Don't forget to use `gridview:true`. Using the `data` parameter and  `gridview:true` you can archive the best performance.

Comment: @Oleg: You've definitely given me plenty of information to make this work just about any way I end up designing it.  Thanks!

Comment: @David: You are welcome! I though it is better that you have more different ways which can work. Than you can choose yourself the way which is the best in your environment and which corresponds more your requirements.

Comment: @Oleg What about searching on date or Boolean fields which are formatted?

Comment: @YairNevet: It's important not only how the data are formatted, but also how the data were filled (how the original input data were). It's important to know whether you use grid with local data or remote data and whether you use `loadonce: true` (in case of remote data).

Comment: @Oleg Hi, i'm using local data.

Comment: @YairNevet: In the case you should use the same values for filtering like the value which you use to fill the grid.