# How can I programmatically do a search on a jqgrid without using their built in toolbar

Tags: jqgrid

I need to perform a search action on a jqgrid that has local data but the values for the query would be coming from another ui element in our application not the jqgrid toolbar's search dialog nor header filter ux.

I looked at the api and did not see any way to hook into the search/filter action programmatically. Is there a way to do this? I found some info on search templates for predefined searchs is there a way to run a search template from the grid api so it performs the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is just to add in the `postData` the searching filter (`filters` for example) and set `search` parameter of jqGrid. Then you can reload the grid. As the results the user will see the filtered grid.

Look at [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5750127/315935). I hope you will find all what you need here.

Comment: More on this.. I have created the search filter object. But when I'm searching on a column that is a boolean it complains that it has no toLowerCase function. I tried setting sorttype as a function in the colmodel that returns "1" for true and "0" for false but still get this error. Any hint?

Comment: @claya: You should just post the jqGrid with the test data which you use. The problem is sure in details *how* you use jqGrid or how you fill the data. It's better to do this in the separate question.