# jqgrid filter strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, filtering

Looking at [Oleg solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749723/jqgrid-filtering-records) for jqgrid filtering, I wrote a code to filter my jqgrid. It has the difference to have 3 differents fields of research but only one button to execute the global search. It works quite good but even if the first search is executed correctly, the second search is executed 2 timese, the third search 4 times, the fourth 8 times and so on, causing several issues if I make a lot of searches.
Here's the code:

```
var grid= $("#mygrid");

function executeSearchInSoftgrid() {    
$("#executeSearch").click(function() {
    f = {groupOp:"AND",rules:[]};
    var searchFiler = $("#filterField1").val(), f;
    var searchFiler2 = $("#filterField2").val(), f;
    var searchFiler3 = $("#filterField3").val(), f;
    if (searchFiler.length === 0) {
        grid[0].p.search = false;
        $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:""});
    }
    if (searchFiler2.length === 0) {
        grid[0].p.search = false;
        $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:""});
    }
    if (searchFiler3.length === 0) {
        grid[0].p.search = false;
        $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:""});
    }

    f.rules.push({field:"field1",op:"cn",data:searchFiler});
    f.rules.push({field:"field2",op:"cn",data:searchFiler2});
    f.rules.push({field:"field3",op:"cn",data:searchFiler3});
    grid[0].p.search = true;
    $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:JSON.stringify(f)});
    grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1,current:true}]);
    alert("searching");
});
```

}

Wherever I call the function (loadcomplete, gridcomplete, readyfunction) the behaviour is the same. Any ideas???
Thanks

**EDIT**

Here's the place where I call the function, and it finally works:

```
var initialize = true;
$("#mygrid")
        .jqGrid({
            gridComplete:function () {
                if(initialize == true) {
                executeSearchInSoftgrid();
                initialize = false;
                //....
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the problem in your code is that you placed `$("#executeSearch").click` inside of `executeSearchInSoftgrid` function which you probably call more as one time. The code

```
$("#executeSearch").click(function() {...});
```

is nothing more as as registering of the event handler (the function `function() {...}`) which will be called automatically if the user click on the element having `id="executeSearch"`. You can register  *multiple* event handles to the `click` event. In the case all the callbacks will be called in the order in which there are registered.

So **you should register the callback function only once**. If you would need the call the event handler independent from the user's interaction you would can do this with `$("#executeSearch").triggerHandler('click')` (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/)) or just with `$("#executeSearch").click();`.

Comment: I checked my js file, I call executeSearchInSoftgrid() only one time in loadcomplete

Comment: @Franky: `loadcomplete` will be called **on every grid refresh**. So you bind more and more events on every grid reload/paging/sorting/filtering. You should move the code out of `loadcomplete` after the grid is created.

Comment: tried in gridcomplete, loadcomplete, readyfunction..
the behaviour is always the same, the alert popup 1,2,4,8,16.. times

Comment: @Franky: You should place the code **outside of any callback. You should place the code just after the grid is created**. For example: `$("#grid").jqGrid({/*jqGrid options and callbacks*/}); $("#executeSearch").click(function() {/*the code of your eventhandler*/});`

Comment: @Franky: Sorry, but you should post the code which you use or post the URL to the demo. I suppose that you don't remove some old calls of `executeSearchInSoftgrid` from `loadcomplete`, `gridcomplete` and so on. Moreover the whole code have to be inside of `jQuery.ready` of cause.

Comment: Can't post my full code here, believe there are no old calls in the js file.

Comment: Moreover is the function is called more then one time, also in the first call there will be a strange behaviour