# How to use JQGrid filter toolbar for incremental-searching on client-side?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, client-side

Can I accomplish this and can I do so with client-side searching?
I want to implement something like Google's "Google Instant" so that I can search without pushing enter.

Comment: Do you mean the option `searchOnEnter: false` of the [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) or something else?

Comment: Oh that was perfect, I'm not sure how I missed that! I thought it would have to be something more complicated. Thanks Oleg- your comments have been a great help in my jqgrid exploration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jqGrid client-side searching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492963/jqgrid-client-side-searching)