# jqGrid filterToolbar and local searching not working

Tags: jqgrid

I have a problem with filtering local data. If I remove loadonce parameter and fetching result from server everything works good. Problem appear when I want filter on local data.
This is my grid implementation:

```
orderPosGrid.jqGrid({
        colNames: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ID', 'Nazwa/Rodzaj', 'Ilość', 'Jedn.', 'Przyczyna zwrotu', 'Napis', '', ''],
        colModel: [
            {name: 'myac', index:'myac', width:0, hidden:true},
            {name: 'commited', index: 'commited', width: 0, editable: false, hidden: true},
            {name: 'hasIlosc', index: 'hasIlosc', width: 0, editable: false, hidden: true},
            {name: 'hasOpis', index: 'hasOpis', width: 0, editable: false, hidden: true},
            {name: 'opisCount', index: 'opisCount', width: 0, editable: false, hidden: true},
            {name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 0, sorttype: 'int', editable: false, hidden: true},
            {name: 'qType', index: 'qType', width: 0, sorttype: 'int', editable: false, hidden: true},
            {name: 'id_prod', index: 'id', width: 30, sorttype: 'int', editable: false},
            {name: 'nazwa', index: 'name', width: 250, editable: false},
            {name: 'ilosc', index: 'quantity', width: 35, align: 'right', sortable: false, search:false, edittype:'text', editable: true, editrules:{custom:true, custom_func:iloscValidate, minValue:1}}, 
            {name: 'jedn', index: 'jedn', width: 35, sortable: false, search:false, align: 'right', editable: false},
            {name: 'opisZwrot', index: 'opisZwrot', width: 170, sortable: false, editable: true, search:false, edittype:'select', formatter: 'select', editoptions:{value:'{{ przyczZwrot }}'}},
            {name: 'opis', index: 'description', width: 170, sortable: false, search:false, editable: true},
           {name: 'group', index: 'group', editable: false, hidden: true},
           {name: 'info', index: 'info', sortable: false, search:false, width: 22}
        ],
        status: 0,
        url: '/ProdList/'+type_id+'/'+order_id+'/',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        ignoreCase:true,
        height: 'auto',
        rowNum: 10000,
        loadonce:true,
        gridview: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortname: '',
        sortorder: '',
        pager: '#ProdList_gridPager',
        caption: 'Lista dostępnych produktów',
        subGrid: false,
        editurl: 'clientArray',
        grouping: true,
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ['group'],
            groupOrder: ['asc'],
            groupColumnShow: [false],
            groupText: ['<b>{0}  [{1}]</b>'],
            groupCollapse: false
        },
...
});
```

I have to filter only on two fields: id and nazwa, others are disabled.
My json data from server looks like:

```
{"total":1, "page":"1", "records":"266", "rows":[{"id": "2473_1", "cell":["","1","0","0","","116","1","2473","Adwokat","3","kg.","","","d - Ciasta kremowo-śmietanowe"]},{"id": "2473_2", "cell":["","1","0","0","","116","1","2473","Adwokat","2","kg.","","","d - Ciasta kremowo-śmietanowe"]},{"id": "2473_3", "cell":["","1","1","1","70","116","1","2473","Adwokat","","kg.","","","d - Ciasta kremowo-śmietanowe"]}]}
```

I think I use typical data configuration and don't need jsonReader configuration.
Am I wrong?
Please help if You find some bug in my code.

Comment: did u try it with jsonReader Configuration?

Comment: Yes I try with this code:
    jsonReader : {
             root : "rows",
             page : "page",
             total : "total",
             records : "records",
             repeatitems : true,
             cell : "cell",
             id : "id"
         },
with no success - still data disappear when I put some letter in filterToolbar field.

Answer (score 0):

check this answer from Oleg. [jqGrid client-side searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492963/jqgrid-client-side-searching)

if you are searching for something then you need to implement it, so where is your implementation code? check the above link, he's saving search criteria there.

Comment: This answer is for single field search, but I use filterToolbar. Anyway thanks for response.
Of course I use: 
orderPosGrid.filterToolbar({ searchOnEnter: false, stringResult: true});

Comment: Anyone have similar problem with filterToolbar? when I put something in fileter fields every row disappear. Thanks for any advice.